# Disabling RC4 ciphers on an IIS server - what browsers will be affected

Tags: iis, rc4-cipher

Following a security audit we've been advised to stop supporting RC4, apparently doing so is [easy enough](https://samrueby.com/2015/06/08/how-to-disable-sslv3-and-rc4-ciphers-in-iis/). However, we support browser back to version IE7 and while I've read extensively on this topic online I cannot find a single decent (read official) source that says what browsers will be affected by this change should we implement it.

What I have found out is that it's XP machines that will be affected and within that bracket there are three versions of IE - 6,7 and 8.

Version 6 we don't support so that's fine, but can anyone say if 7 and 8 will be affected by this? Our site is e-commerce and so the inability to use the SSL pages would be quite a big deal, even if the browser versions are old now.

Has anyone done this on IIS? Were IE7/8 on XP still able to access the secure areas of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your site with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/. The results have a list of client/browser support, including various versions of Internet Explorer.